# How to use FormClass ? [PlayFramework]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

How to use class B in Result A conversationForm ?

```
public static Result A() {
    Form<Conversation> conversationForm = form(Conversation.class).bindFromRequest();
    return TODO;

}

public static Result B() {
    //I want this 
    //return(abc.render(conversationForm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`form(T)` has method `fill(Object)` so you can fill it with some object

```
public static Result B() {
    Conversation conversation = Conversation.find.byId(123);
    Form<Conversation> conversationForm = form(Conversation.class).fill(conversation);
    return(abc.render(conversationForm);
}
```